# Why is my poetry virtualenv using the system python instead of the pyenv python that I set?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv, python-poetry

I've recently installed both Pyenv and Poetry and want to create a new Python 3.8 project. I've set both the `global` and `local` versions of python to `3.8.1` using the appropriate Pyenv commands (`pyenv global 3.8.1` for example). When I run `pyenv version` in my terminal the output is `3.8.1.` as expected.

Now, the problem is that when I create a new python project with Poetry (`poetry new my-project`), the generated `pyproject.toml` file creates a project with python 2.7:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "my-project"
version = "0.1.0"
description = ""
authors = ["user <user@email.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^2.7"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^4.6"

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=0.12"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"
```

It seems that Poetry defaults back to the system version of Python. How do I change this so that it uses the version installed with Pyenv?

**Edit**

I'm using MacOS, which comes bundled with Python 2.7. I think that might be causing some of the issues here. I've reinstalled Python 3.8 again with Pyenv, but when I hit `Poetry install` I get the following error:

```
The currently activated Python version 2.7.16 is not supported by the project (^3.8).
Trying to find and use a compatible version.

[NoCompatiblePythonVersionFound]
Poetry was unable to find a compatible version. If you have one, you can explicitly use it via the "env use" command.
```

Should I create an environment explicitly for the project using Pyenv or should the project be able to access the correct Python version after running `pyenv local 3.8.1.`? When I do the latter, nothing changes and I still get the same errors.

Comment: Does [this issue](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/172) help you / clarify the status?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Alright, I figured the problem. A little embarrassingly, I had not run `pyenv shell 3.8.1` before running any of the other commands. Everything works now. Thank you all for your efforts.

Comment: Interestingly, I needed to do this, even though I had a `.python-version` with the correct version in the directory.

Comment: If the `.python-version` is not being read, you might need to fix your `pyenv` configuration: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv#basic-github-checkout

Comment: This is the solution to most of the problems I have. (And embarrassingly, I need to google this answer every time I do this!) Thank you.

Comment: @juanmirocks that was exactly the issue in my case - I re-configured `pyenv` to use the updated logic and `.python-version` is now discovered properly by `poetry`: `Upgrade note: The startup logic and instructions have been updated for simplicity in 2.3.0. The previous, more complicated configuration scheme for 2.0.0-2.2.5 still works.`

Answer (score 43):

**My solution to this.**

First of all see the situation with this command

```
poetry env list
```

If you have an output like this: ***project_name-QI_LjVaV-py3.9 (Activated)***

you may want to get rid of this env.

So you do the "deactivation" first:

```
deactivate
```

and then the "remove" after :

```
poetry env remove project_name-QI_LjVaV-py3.9
```

Now the same command:

```
poetry env list
```

should return nothing.

Then you do:

```
which python3
```

and, if the version is ok, you use this same exact output of the path of python, to tell to poetry
(Example):

```
poetry env use /usr/bin/python3
```

Do again

```
poetry env info
```

to be sure that is using the version of the python you want.

You can continue with

```
poetry install
```

Comment: Thanks! This solved the issue for me after trying many other solutions for an hour. I think removing the created env was key.

Comment: @SaTa correct, the poetry documentation states: "If a virtual environment has already been created for the project under `{cache-dir}/virtualenvs`, setting this variable to `true` will not cause `poetry` to create or use a local virtual environment. In order for this setting to take effect for a project already in that state, you must delete the virtual environment folder located in `{cache-dir}/virtualenvs`."

https://python-poetry.org/docs/configuration/#virtualenvsin-project

Answer (score 37):

`pyproject.toml` is used to define all the dependencies for your project, including the supported python version.

The line your complaining about is just saying that the versions of python supported by the project is python2.7 or greater, this is independent of what versions of python you've installed with pyenv.

```
python = "^2.7"
```

If you want to update the versions of python supported by the project you can edit the file directly and run `poetry update`.

---

If you want to use multiple versions of python you need to make sure poetry is using the correct dependencies for the version of python you are using. To change the specific version poetry is using you should use `poetry env`,

- `poetry env list` show the versions of python poetry can use
- `poetry env use <python>` switches poetry to use that version.

For instance on my machine poetry has 3 virtual environments  installed and is using the one associated with python3.6:

```
↪ poetry env list
sipy-a9sqc5pb-py3.6 (Activated)
sipy-a9sqc5pb-py3.7
sipy-a9sqc5pb-py3.8
```

I'm not sure how these virtual environments with interact with the shivs used by pyenv but their [docs](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) have a section relating to it

> **Managing Virtual Environments**
>
> There is a pyenv plugin named pyenv-virtualenv which comes with various features to help pyenv users to manage virtual environments created by virtualenv or Anaconda. Because the activate script of those virtual environments are relying on mutating $PATH variable of user's interactive shell, it will intercept pyenv's shim style command execution hooks. We'd recommend to install pyenv-virtualenv as well if you have some plan to play with those virtual environments.

Comment: "Poetry should manage all your python dependencies so that there is no need to use pyenv."—pyenv isn't for _dependencies_. It manages versions of _Python itself_. Does Poetry do that natively?

Comment: Ah my mistake. The keypoint is that the `pyproject.toml` file is saying that your project supports python2.7 or great, it is not saying 'I want to use python3.8'. If you want to update the versions of python your project supports then update toml file directly

Comment: I've updated my answer, hopefully it makes more sense now.

Comment: Great answer, thanks. Although I do have a follow-up question: How do I increase the number of virtual environment options for Poetry? When I run `poetry env list` now, there's only one option and that's for Python 2.7. What I'd like then is to also have and option for Python 3.8 for example.

Comment: I think you want something like: `poetry use python3.8` to switch to 3.8, and then `poetry install` to create the virtual env for 3.8

Comment: I have no idea if the command changed over the last year, but I think the current command is `poetry env use python3.8` . Source: https://web.archive.org/web/20210130151158/https://python-poetry.org/docs/managing-environments/

Comment: `poetry env use` fixed my problem.  Haven't dug into details yet, but I'm guessing I initially created the poetry env (via `poetry install`) with 3.10, then added a .python-version for 3.11, but poetry remembered creating the venv using 3.10, and complained about the mismatch.

Answer (score 34):

you can specify an explicit python executable for poetry using

```
poetry env use <path to python executable>
```

This worked for me.

Comment: The other answers didn't work for me, but this one did. `poetry` is such a moving target (argh...) that I suspect the others ones are obsolete. This one deserves to be pushed to the top.

Comment: Worked for me on Windows with multiple versions of Python installed. Just put the path in quotes and point it to whichever version you want.

Answer (score 17):

On my machine I was able to fix the "currently activated Python version is not supported by the project" error by reinstalling Poetry:

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --uninstall
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

After that,`poetry` was able to find the correct version installed by `pyenv`.

Comment: This resolved my instance of the same issue.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I had to **delete and recreate the virtualenv** used by poetry. This is because I added the python version restrictions (e.g. `python = ">=3.6.2 <3.7"`) after creating the virtualenv.

### Steps

- Delete the original one: run `poetry env remove myApp-XkghI9p6-py3.6`
- Run any poetry step, to create it, or run `poetry shell`, and confirm `poetry run python --version` is the correct version.

Answer (score 3):

First I manually modified `pyproject.toml` and set

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.11.4"
```

Later in CLI

To deactivate the virtual env:

```
exit
```

To remove the virtual env

```
# rm -rf <path_to_virtual_env> 
# in my case:
rm -rf .venv
```

To set the local Python version (sets `.python-version` file)

```
pyenv local 3.11.4
```

To change Poetry env's Python version (**TBH this might be the only command you need**):

```
poetry env use 3.11.4
```

To activate a new virtual env:

```
poetry shell
```

And you should be all good to go. Check Python version with:

```
python -V
```

Answer (score 1):

in my case i was running poetry via python version installed in homebrew but i tried to connect it to pyenv's python version. (since it is installed via  pip i guess....)

I detected it by running:

```
$ where poetry

$ /opt/homebrew/bin/poetry
```

what worked is to remove it and install poetry again via pip in the desired version and use it the same way:

```
pyenv shell python3.11
python -m pip install poetry
python -m poetry install
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though this issue has been resolved, I am writing this for somebody who comes across this problem again.
After all attempts my python -V always resulted in 2.7 and no discussions mentioned running pyenv shell  (surprising to me!)
Adding pyenv to path

```
$ echo -e 'if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then\n eval "$(pyenv init -)"\nfi' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

In my case I had to add it to .bashrc and not bash_profile.
https://ggkbase-help.berkeley.edu/how-to/install-pyenv/

Worked!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the environment was messed up in some way that poetry failed to activate the virtualenv properly.

Try using a different shell: perhaps, sh, or zsh. If everything works in that shell, this proves that your environment is as messed up as mine was :)

Use this command in both shells:

```
$ env
```

and try to spot the difference

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the python version from `pyproject.toml` file and then run `Poetry install`

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to run `python3.8 -m poetry install`.

Comment: `python.exe: No module named poetry`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone not using the venv and came looking for the answer on making poetry use specific version of python :
Upgrade `pip` to latest version
`python3.x -m pip install --upgrade pip`
and then install poetry for that python version
`python3.x -m pip install poetry`

Answer (score 0):

### If you installed Poetry with pipx

Things are a bit different if you installed and manage Poetry using pipx.

**NOTE: Below replace the `python312` command below with whatever will run the newest python, such as `py` or `py -3.12` on windows for v3.12, similarly, replace `python37` with whatever runs your older python version.**

Here's my recommendation in this case:

1. Install pipx for the newest python:

   - `python312 -m pip install --user pipx`
   - At this point pipx will be installed to both your old and new python user folders.
2. Run pipx with list command to see what is installed. All prior installations with the old python version should still be there. The list command will tell you what Python version they were installed with. If you use the alternate way of running pipx as a module, you can force it to run with any version of python:

   - `python312 -m pipx list`
3. Uninstall the current poetry

   - `python312 -m pipx uninstall poetry`
4. Now use the newer python and pipx to install specific Python versions of poetry, using the `--suffix` flag to change the name of the installed file:

   - `python37 -m pipx install --suffix 37 poetry`

     - This will create a `poetry37` entry
   - `python312 -m pipx install --suffix 312 poetry`

     - This will create a `poetry312` entry

Although, personally, I made the poetry 3.12 version just `poetry` and then used `poetry37` for the older python 3.7 version. Now I will run most things going forward with just `poetry`, but for 3.7 specific tasks I can use `poetry37`.

In addition, I changed the path to point to the Python 3.12 Scripts folder instead of 3.7 so the newer version of pipx could run directly at the command line without `python -m pipx`

Answer (score -3):

try re-installing poetry again

```
pip uninstall poetry
pip install poetry
```