# nox does not find my pyenv versions in my Python Poetry project

Tags: python, pyenv, python-poetry, nox

I have a python project and I have tried to follow the [Hypermodern Python Project guidelines](https://cjolowicz.github.io/posts/hypermodern-python-02-testing) for testing with `Poetry` and `nox` and `pyenv`.

This is on Debian 10 running on WLS2.

```
> lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:        10
Codename:       buster
```

I have these versions of Python installed with `pyenv`:

```
> pyenv versions
  system
  3.10.2
* 3.7.12 
* 3.8.12 
* 3.9.10
```

and versions 3.7.12, 3.8.12 and 3.9.10 are enabled for this project with `pyenv local`.

In my `noxfile.py` my `tests` session is like this:

```
@session(python=["3.7", "3.9", "3.8"])
def tests(session: Session) -> None:
    """Run the test suite."""
    session.install(".")
    session.install("coverage[toml]", "pytest")
    session.run("pytest", *args)
```

I would expect that when I invoke `nox` to run my tests with `poetry run nox -s tests`, it would run in all three of these versions of Python, as shown in the [Hypermodern example](https://cjolowicz.github.io/posts/hypermodern-python-02-testing/#:%7E:text=%24%20nox%0A%0Anox%20%3E%20Running,tests%2D3.7%3A%20success).

Instead, I see this:

```
nox > Running session tests-3.7
nox > Creating virtual environment (virtualenv) using python3.7 in .nox/tests-3-7
nox > poetry build --format=wheel
...
nox > Session tests-3.7 was successful.
nox > Running session tests-3.9
nox > Session tests-3.9 skipped: Python interpreter 3.9 not found.
nox > Running session tests-3.8
nox > Session tests-3.8 skipped: Python interpreter 3.8 not found.
nox > Ran multiple sessions:
nox > * tests-3.7: success
nox > * tests-3.9: skipped
nox > * tests-3.8: skipped
```

I have tried various combinations of `pyenv global` and `pyenv local`. I have run `poetry upgrade` after setting the multiple version with `pyenv`. Ditto re-running `poetry install`.

I have been unsuccessful searching for an answer on the interwebs and I'm hoping someone here can point me on the right path.

I ran `pyenv shell 3.8.12` etc., as hinted in a related [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59810276/poetry-doesnt-use-the-correct-version-of-python), but that did not seem to do the trick. That same article suggested updating `~/.profile` and `~/.bashrc`, but that did not help either.

I uninstalled and reinstalled `poetry`:

```
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 - --uninstall
curl -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org | python3 -
```

and no change.

I also chased the ideas from this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70950511/using-poetry-with-pyenv-and-having-python-version-issues), to no avail.

Comment: if you are on linux , can you check this one?https://stackoverflow.com/a/68228627/4683950

Comment: Thank you for this link, @Espoir. It lead me to a solution for my problem that I will post in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**
Based on the tip from Espoir Murhabazi to focus on this [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321312/cannot-switch-python-with-pyenv/68228627#68228627), I focused on the `pyenv` leg of the triangle. After reading and experimenting more with getting my bash `PATH` right for `pyenv`, I was eventually able to get the expected results when I run `poetry run nox -s tests` after `pyenv local 3.7.12 3.8.12 3.9.10`. That is:

```
nox > Ran multiple sessions:
nox > * tests-3.7: success
nox > * tests-3.9: success
nox > * tests-3.8: success
```

Sweet success!

What ended up doing:

I removed any reference to `Poetry` and `pyenv` that had crept into my `.bash_profile` and my `.bashrc`.  At the end of my `.profile` I ended up with these commands which did the trick:

```
...
# set PATH so it includes Poetry bin so I can manage my Python projects
export PATH="$HOME/.poetry/bin:$PATH"

# set up pyenv so I can use al the versions of Python I want
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv init --path)"
```

This sets up `pyenv` then `poetry` early in my path.  I think they may have been later in the path before I started messing around. My `PATH` now looks like this, and all is well between `pyenv`, `Poetry` and `nox`.  Thank you @Espoir Murhabazi.

```
PATH=~/.local/bin:/home/me/.pyenv/plugins/pyenv-virtualenv/shims:/home/me/.pyenv/shims:/home/me/.pyenv/bin:/home/me/.poetry/bin:/home/me/.local/bin:/home/me/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games
```

Poring over the [pyenv README](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/blob/master/README.md#understanding-path) helped arrive at this solution.